# Qt Widgets. Форматирование текста.

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

Есть функция, которая при выводе текста на виджет Textedit (chat_edit), выравнивает его по левому краю через Qt::AlignLeft. Я хочу, чтоб, когда я получу текст, то он был выравнен по правому краю. Пробовал изменить Qt::AlignLeft на Qt::AlignRight, но тогда весь текст будет выравнен по правому краю, а не строка. Получается, что хочу, как на картинки ниже. С помощью чего это реализовывать?
 
 [image]

```
void Mwindow::on_send_button_clicked()
{ 
    QString s = ui->send_edit->text();
    ui->send_edit->clear();

    QTextCursor cursor = ui->chat_edit->textCursor();
    QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
    textBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);
    ui->chat_edit->setTextCursor(cursor);

    ui->chat_edit->append("Я: " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы же формат меняте у блока на котором курсор стоит, а потом параграф добавляете в конец документа. У вас одно с другим никак не связано. Логично же сначала добавить параграф, а потом установить ему стиль какой надо. И курсор тут не нужен, просто берете последний параграф.